# Sitecore Custom Role based User gets disabled on package installation

Tags: packages, user-management

I created a package of users and roles from local development environment of Sitecore.NET 9.0.1 (rev. 171219).

When this package is installed on Azure , users got disabled.

I know we can enable them from User Manager but would like to know, why this had happened?

Has anyone faced similar situation?

[image]

Comment: Passwords. They cannot transfer across.

Comment: @MarkCassidy , yes the passwords also were changed.

So , is this a normal behavior with User package installation on another instance ?

Comment: The [KB article on password transfer](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/242631) suggests that it is set to a random password (and not disabled). I wonder if something has changed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a normal behaviour in Sitecore but you can transfer the password between environments.

**Note**: This solution applies only to the default SQL Membership Provider provided used by Sitecore.

You need to follow next steps:

1. IMPORTANT! Back up your databases.
2. Copy the [TransferUserPasswords.aspx](https://kb.sitecore.net/~/media/577C27A0A2C44A26B8EAAE4E93369CCE.ashx?la=en) file to the \sitecore\admin folder of your solution.
3. Request the page using the URL as below:
   **/sitecore/admin/TransferUserPasswords.aspx**
4. Enter the connection strings of the source and target Core databases using appropriate text boxes.
5. Click the Refresh button to get the list of users that exist in both Core databases.
6. Use the <<< and >>> buttons to select or deselect users for password transferring.
7. Click the Transfer button.

   After performing these steps, passwords of the selected users will be transferred to the target Core database.

   More information you can find [here](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/242631) .